# Get function of Table of values in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, regression

I'm working with this table:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OTJX3DDwl3iAr6L-ABBI9QYzl1rvoUAMi4ZkPIWbKls/edit?usp=sharing

```
Here's an excerpt of the data:
+-------------+------------+---------------+
|   Damage    |   HB IV    | Honorar HB IV |
+-------------+------------+---------------+
| 500,00 €    | 207,00 €   | 41,40%        |
| 750,00 €    | 240,00 €   | 32,00%        |
| 1.250,00 €  | 315,00 €   | 25,20%        |
| 2.250,00 €  | 412,00 €   | 18,31%        |
| 2.500,00 €  | 434,00 €   | 17,36%        |
| 3.250,00 €  | 492,00 €   | 15,14%        |
| 3.500,00 €  | 511,00 €   | 14,60%        |
| 3.750,00 €  | 529,00 €   | 14,11%        |
| 4.000,00 €  | 547,00 €   | 13,68%        |
| 4.250,00 €  | 564,00 €   | 13,27%        |
| 4.500,00 €  | 581,00 €   | 12,91%        |
| 4.750,00 €  | 597,00 €   | 12,57%        |
| 8.500,00 €  | 797,00 €   | 9,38%         |
| 9.000,00 €  | 823,00 €   | 9,14%         |
| 9.500,00 €  | 849,00 €   | 8,94%         |
| 10.000,00 € | 877,00 €   | 8,77%         |
| 12.500,00 € | 1.003,00 € | 8,02%         |
| 13.000,00 € | 1.030,00 € | 7,92%         |
| 14.500,00 € | 1.104,00 € | 7,61%         |
| 15.000,00 € | 1.132,00 € | 7,55%         |
| 20.000,00 € | 1.352,00 € | 6,76%         |
| 28.000,00 € | 1.731,00 € | 6,18%         |
| 29.000,00 € | 1.776,00 € | 6,12%         |
| 30.000,00 € | 1.834,00 € | 6,11%         |
+-------------+------------+---------------+
```

I need a function, where I can determine the Provision HB IV (Col. J) and the Percentage of the Damage (Col. K) based on the Damage (Col. B).

Can someone help me? I tried for about one hour with no visible success.

I tried to create a graph and print out the exp. function but I had a lot of problems with that. The closest thing to a solution was `f(x)=298,7145055672 exp(0,0339503314x)` and `-0.0786286785ln(x) + 0.3607031908` but I think there must be a more independent way to calculate this equation.

EDIT:

[image]

But it's still to hard coded, because if I change some values, I have to redraw the whole thing etc..

Beside this, the graph for the percentage will become negative whilst it should only converge towards zero.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please include any sample data **in the question**. Downloading data from unknown sources is not advised.  See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: @DavidPostill It's no download link; it's just a viewable Google Document. But I will convert a few lines in an ASCII table

Comment: Note also we are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Are you asking how to perform non-linear regression analysis in Excel? Or are you asking what kind of function you should use to model this relationship? Or both?

Comment: @Excellll Hi, indeed, I'm asking for both.